# STM32F303 STM32CubeMX __HAL_TIM_SetCompare macro does not exist

Tags: pwm, stm32, stm32cubemx, nucleo

I am using CubeMX to generate code for my NucleoF303. I am a bit confused how to set the pulse width of a timer in PWM mode.

Previously (using an F4) there has been a __HAL_TIM_SetCompare macro in the stm32fxxx_hal_tim.h file.

But that does not exist. Am I supposed to set the duty cycle in some other manner?

Of course I can just directly set the CCRx registers. That works. But if I am going to use a HAL with lots of abstraction like cube seems to be, I would at least like to know how they intend me to use it. Even if I don't.

Not really any code to go with this question.. But here is my current commit in case it is useful:
https://github.com/c-herring/Sumo2017_NucleoF303/tree/221dc57a305ccd64a4b98726df3cce02720b280b

Cheers!

Comment: Well you can check the STM32CubeF3 HAL description, but there are nothing for you as far as I know, apart from re-configuring the entire channel. `__HAL_TIM_SetCompare` this just sets the CCRx register directly anyway. So IMO it is OK at it is now.

Answer (score 4):

> Previously (using an F4) there has been a __HAL_TIM_SetCompare macro in the stm32fxxx_hal_tim.h file.

That was indeed some time ago. I've found a copy of STM32CubeF4 V1.6.0 (released 28-May-2015) lying around in an old project directory, and it already has the following alias definition

```
Inc/Legacy/stm32_hal_legacy.h:#define __HAL_TIM_SetCompare            __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE
```

Digging even deeper, the description of 1.4.0 says

> **STM32CubeF4 Firmware Package V1.4.0 / December 26, 2014**
>
> **Main Changes**
>
> Maintenance release to fix known defects and several enhancements implementation
>
> HAL Macros and literals renaming to ensure compatibles across STM32 series, backward compatibility maintained thanks to new added file stm32_hal_legacy.h under /Inc/Legacy

So, it must be the time when `__HAL_TIM_SetCompare` got deprecated in favor of `__HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE`.

You should still get the alias definition though, because all HAL headers include `stm32_hal_legacy.h`.